# Slow performance Ubuntu 20.04 w/ Dell XPS15

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, performance

I recently purchased a new Dell XPS15, full options:

- Intel core i9-10885H, 64GB DDR4, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 Ti 4 GB GDDR6

Currently running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (focal). Using the recommended Nvidia-driver-460 (proprietary, tested) driver. I did a kernel upgrade to 5.10.12-051012-generic for Wifi drivers, which didn't work out of the box. This is still not working 100%, and wifi is often gone after coming out of sleep/hibernate (requires a full reboot to work again). I'm not that concerned about this one, since I have a wired connection, but still... Not what you'd expect for a new laptop.

My main concern is that the overall performance is just bad.

The average boot time is +2 min. On Shutdown/reboot it sometimes hangs for several minutes, shutting down all services. Starting basic applications (Thunderbird, VS Code) takes +10 secs.
Sometimes applications just don't start at all and crash immediately.
I also noticed from another thread, that I'm experiencing [screen tearing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfL_JkcEFbE).

I really like to get things to work, but not sure where to start. This is the first time I'm running Linux on my personal devices (coming from Macbook pro's), so bear with me. Any help to troubleshoot would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT 1:** After digging around a little bit it seems graphics-drivers aren't actually installed correctly.

Output of `sudo nvidia-smi` is: "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

And `sudo lshw -C display` shows *-display UNCLAIMED for my 3D controller.

Apparently, Nvidia doesn't work with kernel 5.10+ (also see [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/kj19sq/latest_kernel_510_makes_nvidia_driver_to_stop/)). But my wifi and Bluetooth don't work on a lower version. I just tried 5.9.16, but no success.

**EDIT 2:** I ended up trying several other distro's, but returned to Ubuntu. Clean install of the latest 20.10 (groovy), with standard kernel (5.8.0-43), NVIDIA's proprietary, tested 460-drivers and pre-release updates enabled. Everything works smoothly now, except that it's still missing Wifi drivers. As far as found out is that those require kernel 5.10+. I might give that another go at a later stage.

Comment: The XPS 15 is not Ubuntu certified. That doesn’t mean it won’t work properly but you may have issues to overcome. Very new devices like wifi don’t always have good support but it usually improves after a few months. Many machines don’t sleep/hibernate properly with Ubuntu. You might not be able to resolve that. To analyse your boot time try sudo systemd-analyze  and sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain. A google search for those commands will throw up plenty of help

Comment: If you search on Ask Ubuntu for XPS15 there are plenty of answered questions some of which may help. You might also get help on the discord for the Ubuntu podcast

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried a few other distro's, but ended up with a clean/new install of latest Ubuntu. So far so good and everything is running quite smoothly, except for the missing wifi drivers. Updated my main post.

Comment: I did think about suggesting an alternative distro but that’s not really in the spirit of AskUbuntu. However if all else fails you might get better results with Manjaro or Pop!_OS.